# What is the blast radius of enemy grenades?

Tags: mass-effect-3

**How far away do I have to be to avoid damage from grenades?**

I have unfortunately been on the receiving end of them a few times, and they have caused me a lot of frustration every time I get killed by one.

Providing the exact radius in meters will be of little help to me, so an answer with screenshots/visuals will probably be more beneficial.

Comment: typically I find myself safe if I'm 1 'roll length' away from the impact point.  But this is mostly from multiplayer experience, not sure if it translates into single player.

Comment: They're probably the same as player grenades. Do enemies throw just Frag grenades or all types?

Comment: I don't know if enemies have access to the skills that boost grenade radius though.

Comment: Yeah, they're probably level 1 skill across the board

Comment: As far as I can tell they only throw one type of grenade. I believe you're right in assuming they're level 1 grenades (at least in terms of radius).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you just want a picture of it, here you go. I backed off until I was just out of the range where the red warning icon for the grenade appears, and took no damage when this grenade exploded.

[image]

Honestly, though, I'm not sure how this screenshot is going to help you any more than playing a bit will. You'll quickly get a feel for it. The simple rule is if you can see the warning icon flashing, keep running.

A few things of note:

- If you can see the red warning icon flashing for the grenade, you *will* take damage when it explodes unless you're behind cover.
- If you are directly on top of the grenade, a single roll is not enough to take you out of its radius, but two rolls is.
- On Insanity, the grenades do at least 1500 damage, which seems better than mine even when fully upgraded. My Shepard's got about 750 health and 750 shields, and being in a grenade's blast radius always instant-kills me.

Comment: The radius is much bigger than I thought. Specifically, the screenshot helps me gauge how far I need to move during critical moments such as being under fire while behind a small amount of cover. I believe in Hardcore mode that grenades do ~1500 damage at the point of explosion as my Shepard (750/750 like yours) also dies in one shot.

Comment: Really the only thing you need to watch for is the warning icon as Sterno, it's there for exactly this purpose. You're not supposed to need to know the range for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

About 4 meters give or take. Most Sniper rifles have a meter indicator on the right side so just stare at one and back up until the indicator vanishes. I think the multiplayer soldier has a radius of 3 or so without upgrading.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry no screenshots but the impact radius is relatively small.Not more than a meter or a meter and a half (which is pretty small in game lenght)

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, the reason I'm asking for more than a measurement in Mass Effect meters is because that's still too vague and unclear to be useful.

Comment: I say it's more like 1.25 meters.